# Export crystal report to PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

```
ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument();
            crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath(Report));
            crystalReport.SetDatabaseLogon("glfuser", "glfuserpass", "glfcol", "");
            crvReport.RefreshReport();
            crvReport.ReportSource = DAC.GenerateReport(Report, Query);
            crvReport.ID = ReportName;
        crystalReport.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, @"D:\ASD.pdf");
```

Trying to export my report in PDFformat in my local PC after I get report in report viewer. I am getting report but when I am trying to export it with ExportToDisk method I get error

> Database logon failed.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
>   Database logon failed.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 19:             //crvReport.ReportSource =
>   DAC.GenerateReport(Report, Query); Line 20:             //crvReport.ID
>   = ReportName; Line 21:             crystalReport.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat,
>   @"D:\ASD.pdf");

Comment: At a guess - I'd say your database login credentials were wrong, or the database does not exist.

Comment: but when I remove the last line (crystalReport.ExportToDisk..) I am getting my report.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to declare your database at following line

```
crystalReport.SetDatabaseLogon("glfuser", "glfuserpass", "glfcol", "dbname");
```